# Automatic testing of Google Assistant actions

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to set up an actions-on-google-testing library in my current project as described here https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google-testing 
but I am not able to find Device Registration sections and where to register model. I have completed steps 1-3 and need assistant after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable access to the Google Assistant API, do the following:

Open the Actions Console.

GO TO THE ACTIONS CONSOLE

Click on Add/import project.

To create a new project, type a name in the Project name box and click CREATE PROJECT.

If you already have an existing Google Cloud Platform project, you can select that project and import it instead.

[image: Add project]

If you created a new project, click the Device registration box near the bottom of the page. If you imported a previously-created project, this box will not be displayed; select the Device registration tab (under ADVANCED OPTIONS) from the left navbar.

[image: Device registration]

Comment: I have an existing action on console project In Actions Console -> Advanced options. There are only three tabs. Account linking, brand verification, and Backend services. I could not find the device registration tab.

Comment: You may need to create a new project explicitly for *Device Registration*

Comment: After doing all of this, I am getting a problem where there is no build tab in the sidebar in the new project but only device registration coming at the bottom.

Comment: That's fine. As testing happens at the level of a Google account, you can have one project for testing which will work for any other conversational action (once the action is in a testing state)